# nested brackets in Regex

Tags: java, regex

I'm using regex in java to extract data from user entries like these:

```
String entry1 = "add to xx16,John Doe";
String entry2 = "add to ab20,John Doe;Richard Roe;John Stiles";
```

They can have multiple names, but if they do have them they have to be seperated by semicolons. Now I want a regex to give me back those parameters. I came up with that

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("add to ([a-z|\\d]*),([a-zA-Z]*\\s[a-zA-Z]*)[;([a-zA-Z]*\\s[a-zA-Z]*)]*");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(entry);
matcher.matches();
//get inputs with matcher.group();
```

It works well with entries like `entry1`, but it does not with `entry2`. Does anyone see my mistake ?

Comment: What output are you looking for?

Comment: this is not a correct use of a `[...]` character class: `[;([a-zA-Z]*\s[a-zA-Z]*)]`

Comment: In `entry2` the output should be group(0) = "ab20", group(1) = "John Doe", group(2) = "Richard Roe", group(3) = "John Stiles"

Comment: you can't have an unlimited variable number of groups like that. just capture them all then split

Comment: How would I capture them all? Like this: `(;?[a-zA-Z]*\\s[a-zA-Z]*)` ?

Comment: Why can't you `split(";")`, then match whatever?

Comment: Try multiple matching approach: `"(\\p{Alnum}+),([^;]+)"` regex and then `while (matcher.find()) { group(1) and group(2) contain the values you need }`

Comment: How about [using `\G`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/bounds.html) to bind matches on previous: [`"(?:^add to |\\G(?!^))([^,;]+)[,;]?"`](http://fiddle.re/e7ev2n) Grab matches of `group(1)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't have an unlimited variable number of groups like that. Just capture them all then split.

Since you are not testing whether or not the matcher actually matches, I assume you don't care too much about validating the format of the input and just want to grab the values. So you could do something like this:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("add to (\\w+),(.*)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(entry);
matcher.matches(); // FIXME: check if it matches
String[] names = matcher.group(2).split(";");
```

Comment: I do care about validating the format though, I have just removed that part to keep my example simple. Is there no way to do both, validating and get the data at the same time ?

Comment: If you care about validating the format then you need to completely overhaul your regex, because it is not likely doing what you think it is doing. You have not provided enough information yet about what constitutes valid data in order to completely fix your broken regex.

Answer (score 1):

```
Skiping the first 7 characters ( "add to " ) from the beginning using the regular expression (?:^.{7}) and then splitting it with either with comma or semicolon [,;]

String entry1 = "add to xx16,John Doe";
String entry2 = "add to ab20,John Doe;Richard Roe;John Stiles";

String[] str = entry1.split("(?:^.{7})|[,;]");
for(String st : str ){
    System.out.println(st);
}

str = entry2.split("(?:^.{7})|[,;]");
for(String st : str ){
    System.out.println(st);
}
```

output:

```
xx16
John Doe

ab20
John Doe
Richard Roe
John Stiles
```